# Why no point-of-interest detectors in Object Detection/Tracking?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, tracking, detection

I aim to detect and track vehicles with opencv using recorded on-road scenarios in real-time. I realize most of the algorithms/papers use Haar-like-features or HoG as feature-descriptors, and in most literature about vehicle detection there is not much investigation in using point-of-interest based approaches.

I mean in OpenCV there are so many nice edge/corner -based detectors like FAST, ORB, BRISK, ....why don't use them in junction with a nice descriptor and do some matching/classification afterwards?

And when is it actually better to use such a detector/descriptor strategy for object detection compared with a traditional Haar-cascade or HoG/SVM approach? Is it for robustness or performance reasons?

Regards 
Obi